# Showing values from object in select dropdown angular

Tags: angularjs, select

From an API call I am receiving an object that looks like this and assigning it to `$scope.countries`:

```
$scope.countries = {
AU:"Australia",
BE:"Belgium",
US:"United States"
}
```

In my front end I want to add each country to a dropdown list, so that it will show the full country names like the below. I have taken many different approaches but cannot get it to work.

```
- Australia
- Belgium
- United States
```

Please see my code below:

```
<select ng-options="(key, value) in countries" ng-change="getRoles()">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this ,

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.countries = {
AU:"Australia",
BE:"Belgium",
US:"United States"
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="plunker" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
 <select ng-model="country" ng-options="key as value for (key , value) in countries"></select>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `"ng-repeat = item in countries"` and `ng-options={{item}}`